How can I find all violations of a proposed foreign key on all columns with a specific name?
Let's say I have multiple tables with a column foobar. And I wish to make to make all these columns reference foobar.id as a FOREIGN KEY. The problem is I know there are violations in this schema from the party I am importing the data from. But, I would rather not find them all iteratively.
How can I find all of the violations so as to prepare a report of data-integrity issues for the third party?

Using \gexec
This query will generate a query which we can later execute. If we're using psql we can use \gexec to execute the return of the last query -- a feature made specifically for this kind of stuff,
WITH pkey(table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name)
    AS ( VALUES ('db', 'schema', 'table', 'pkey') ),
fkey(column_name) AS ( VALUES ('table_fkey') )
SELECT FORMAT(
    $$
    SELECT DISTINCT %I
    FROM ( %s ) AS v(%I)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM %I.%I.%I AS p
        WHERE p.%I = v.%I
    )
    $$,
    pkey.column_name,
    string_agg( sql.stmt, 'UNION ALL'),
    pkey.column_name,
    pkey.table_catalog, pkey.table_schema, pkey.table_name,
    pkey.column_name,
    pkey.column_name

)
FROM (
    SELECT FORMAT(
        $$
        SELECT %I FROM %I.%I.%I
        $$,
        c.column_name, c.table_catalog, c.table_schema, c.table_name
    )
    FROM information_schema.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN fkey USING ( column_name )
) AS sql(stmt)
CROSS JOIN pkey
GROUP BY pkey.table_catalog, pkey.table_schema, pkey.table_name, pkey.column_name;

Given something like,
WITH pkey(table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name)
    AS ( VALUES ('tec', 'tec', 'codes_schedule', 'schedule_id') ),
fkey(column_name) AS ( VALUES ('schedformtypecd') )
...

It will produce a query like this,
SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id                                   
FROM (                                                        
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_contributiondata
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_creditdata      
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_debtdata        
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_expenddata      
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_expendrepayment 
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_loandata        
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_pledgedata      
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_traveldata      
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_assetdata       
        UNION ALL                                             
        SELECT schedformtypecd FROM tec.tec.c_candidatedata   
         ) AS v(schedule_id)                                  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                                            
        SELECT 1                                              
        FROM tec.tec.codes_schedule AS p                      
        WHERE p.schedule_id = v.schedule_id                   
)                                                             
AND schedule_id is NOT NULL                                   

Which after you run \gexec will output
 schedule_id 
-------------
 A
 B2
 M
 t-ctr
(4 rows)

Which is all the exceptions in the database that would prevent you from making a blanket foreign key on schedformtypecd to tec.tec.codes_schedule.schedule_id

Example taken from db-Texas-Ethics-Commission
